# How to rip specific data from an HTML file?

Tags: php, regex

so I have multiple HTML files which I need to get some praticular data from, I mean theres a bunch of non relative information in this HTML files, but I need just lets say things that are between the `<div class="myInfo">` and `</div>`, after getting this information I want to handle it in my own PHP page, so for example I can insert this data into some variables. Is it even possible using PHP only?
(Forgive me for my English mistakes)

Comment: Do you have some samples of the data you wish to process? Have you tried anything as of yet? (If so, explain what, and what went wrong) Are you familiar with PHP HTML libraries such as Simple HTML Parser (http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)? What about using regular expressions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: @Baur - Is is not smart to use regular expressions to parse html.

Comment: @Oren: I understand that, however, firstly: I was trying to engage the asker in dialogue to understand what (s)he had attempted; secondly: I wasn't necessarily suggesting that the HTML itself should be parsed using regular expressions. The intent of the asker was initially unclear (see the previous revisions: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2994339/revisions) and if it was a case of simple-language parsing that was needed, then regular expressions wouldn't be a *bad* solution.

Comment: @Bauer - I apologize for my jumpiness in restating the popular StackOverflow catch phrase.  I hope the original poster has found what he is looking for.

Comment: The SimpleDom solution works great for me. Much appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use SimpleDom

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
// Find all article blocks
foreach(file_get_html('http://smysite.com')->find('div.myInfo') as $Info) {
    print_r($Info);
}
```

Alternative.
http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: This is the ultimate tool for DOM Parsing. along side PHP's XMLDOM Functions,, but this is a simple easy starter - i updated post because i posted incorrect link. please review

Comment: That's working just great, this tool is very powerful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use CURL for that

Here is a link
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php